Подскажите пожалуйста, почему вылезает ошибка отношение users не существует postgres python
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему вылезает ошибка отношение users не существует

отношение "users" не существует LINE 1: SELECT id FROM users

import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", user="postgres", password="", host="localhost", port="5433") 
print("Database opened successfully")

cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT id FROM users')
all_users= cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
con.close()

К базе данных подключение работает, сама таблица users есть

Точную ошибку процитируйте в кавычках пожалуйста в вопросе

ОШИБКА:  отношение "users" не существует
LINE 1: SELECT id FROM users

Вариант 1: у пользователя нет прав на чтение таблицы, необходимо выдать:
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO myuser;

Вариант 2: таблица с заглавной буквой, нужно заключить в кавычки:
SELECT * FROM "Users";

Вариант 3: таблица не в схеме public, укажите нужную:
SELECT * FROM test.users;

